# What is ${session.executionRootDirectory} and how to set it

Tags: java, maven, deeplearning4j

I am using dl4j examples in my system. It's a maven project with various modules. There are several pom files in it. In the parent pom file I noticed I got an error stating:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'session.executionRootDirectory'

.

I don't remember changing this line (or this pom file either). The line producing the problem is this one:

```
<configFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/contrib/formatter.xml</configFile>
```

in file [parent pom file](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/pom.xml) line 90.

My question is since `${session.executionRootDirectory}` seems as a variable which my system fails to identify is it something of an environment variable I should set? Should this be set by another way?
Any idea of what `${session.executionRootDirectory}` is and how to set it welcome.

My system is win7 and I am using Intellij Idea.

The problem seem to be solved by replacing the variable with an actual value of the path to the file it points to (that is *formatter.xml*) but I would like to know why the solution with the variable does not work.

Comment: It's a maven property check : https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html

Comment: In the maven instruction it refers to a Settings.xml file. Where is supposed that file to be?

Comment: I think in .m2/settings.xml. You can also set a specific path, see documentation : https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: alain don't you want to write an answer so I can choose it as solution?

Comment: Sure, feel free to edit it to add details if needed. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think that session.executionRootDirectory is a configuration in settings.xml. session is a root object that has the method getExecutionRootDirectory(). See https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession.html

Comment: IntelliJ Ticket related to this matter: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147984

Answer (score -2):

Values between `${...}` are Maven property. You can read the documentation for a detailed explanation [here](https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html).

Values have to be be configured in a `settings.xml` file.

This file may live in:

- The Maven install: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
- A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

For more details about `settings.xml`, check the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: Sorry, it seems that eventually this didn't solve my problem so I couldn't accept is as an answer.

Answer (score -3):

No it is in your project path:

```
dl4j-examples/contrib/formatter.xml
```